# How to prevent cut off div with background when window is too small

Tags: html, css

I have problem with the background div, when I resize the window too much, the browser cut off the left and top side of that div (background image).

How can I stop that?

That is my index.html

```
<div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='background'></div>
        <div id='menu'></div>
        <div id='lang'></div>
        <div id='content'></div>
        <div id='contact'></div>
    </div>
```

And css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    top: 25%;
}

#background {
    background-image: url('gfx/6_small.jpg');

    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;

        min-height: 657px;
        min-width: 1218px;

    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a fixed pixel margin on `#wrapper` like so:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

and remove the negative `margin-left` and `margin-top` from `#background` this should not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement additional spritesheets to style your site according to smaller devices (or smaller windows) with CSS3 media queries.

For instance, for browsers with a width less than 900px, you could style everything smaller and apply other background-images to certain elements.

[W3C MediaQueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

[What it looks like](http://mediaqueri.es/)

To update it livetime, you will furthermore need [response.js](http://responsejs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have conflicting position rules (i.e. your using both % and px). If you need a non-flexible layout that doesn't shrink with the browser size you need to avoid %. One way I like to do this is put all my content in a wrapper `div` (everything, header, content...etc.), and then assign a background color that goes well with my design to the body element.